# want to use data through a join column, but the fetched data is showing as null, even though it is present in the Hibernate interceptor (springboot)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am having a class shippingOrder and another class shipment.

ShippingOrder

```
@Entity
@Table(name="shipping_order")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class ShippingOrder implements Serializable {
@JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "shipment_id")
    private Shipment shipment;
}
```

and shipment Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shipment")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Shipment implements Serializable {
@JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "shipping_order_id")
    private ShippingOrder shippingOrder;
}
```

[image]

It is showing null here but data is present in hibernate interceptor

[image]

I am also getting an error in fetching awb data
Error message :

```
Method threw 'javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.hk.admin.entities.Awb$HibernateProxy$EQfa2R8Q.toString()
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Solution :
**Check your database thoroughly to ensure that the data is present.**

In my case:

**There is no data present in the AWB corresponding to the AWB ID in the shipment table.**

Extra tips:

- Check vpn connection
- Verify code ( specially Repository code )